# Can I find execution times of OpenGL commands in the XCode GPU Frame Capture?

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, xcode6, gpu

Something is taking ages to render and causing my device to slow.

I'm using XCode 6.2 and I've have a captured a GPU frame from my game on iOS.

I can see all the OpenGL ES commands but I'm finding it difficult to see which one is the one taking all the time.  Can anyone help me or give me any tips?

Thanks,
- Rich

Answer (score 0):

Have tried Xocdes->Instruments ? If not follow the steps

1) In menu bar select "Xcode-> Instruments"

2) Choose "Timer Profile"

3) Then In "Targets" section select your app

4) Click on "Record" button (Red color) , then it start running
While running it shows list of tasks with the execution time

5) Trace out in the list for your solution.

I will post with the images later just now i can't.